# Is there any easier way to code this in JavaScript (while loop and switch statement)?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, switch-statement

I am wondering if there is another easier way to get the same result of such code in JavaScript. I used ***while loop*** for decreasing the number each time but then I had to use ***switch statement*** to change the word "**bottles**" in the string from plural to singular as the number of bottles drops to 1 then 0.

```
var num = 99;
//The following code repeats the sentence with changing number gradually.
while (num>2) {
console.log(num + " bottles of juice on the wall! " + num + 
" bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around..." + (num-1) 
+ " bottles of juice on the wall!" );
num = num - 1;

}

//then this code is for bottle to be singular as the number decrease to be 1 
then zero
switch (num){

case 2 :
console.log(num + " bottles of juice on the wall! " + num + 
" bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around..." + (num-1) 
+ " bottle of juice on the wall!" );


case 1 :
console.log((num-1) + " bottles of juice on the wall! " + (num-1) + 
" bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around..." + (num-2) 
+ " bottle of juice on the wall!" );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd make a function that returns the word in either plural or singular form.

```js
function bottles(num) {
  if( num === 1 ) {
    return '1 bottle';
  }
  
  return num + ' bottles';
}

for( var num = 99; num > 0; num-- ) {
  console.log(bottles(num) + " of juice on the wall! " + bottles(num) +
    " of juice! Take one down, pass it around... " + bottles(num - 1) +
    " of juice on the wall!");
}
```

Comment: thank you . i am just a beginner and started to learn loops with while loop and then this was a quiz on while loop. I think that you used for loop and functions that I heard about but  haven't learnt them yet.